# What is A2tUiModule in Angular 2?

Tags: javascript, angular

I am getting this error when using angular2-token and A2tUiModule

" ERROR in A2tUiModule is not an NgModule "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can refer to https://github.com/neroniaky/angular-token/issues/138
If your version is same then you may need to install the fixed version.

```
npm install angular-token
```

Then you can import `import { AngularTokenModule } from 'angular-token';`

`@NgModule({
    imports: [
        ...,
        HttpClientModule,
        AngularTokenModule.forRoot({
          ...
        })
    ],
    declarations: [ ... ],
    providers:    [ AngularTokenModule ],
    bootstrap:    [ ... ]
})`

Answer (score 0):

A2tUIMOdule is part of Angular2Token. You need to import it in your main module.ts file :

```
import { A2tUiModule } from 'angular2-token';
```